# Is there a unitary transformation such that the Hamiltonian in the time-dependent Schrödinger equation becomes real symmetric?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, time-evolution

The time-dependent Schroödinger equation is given as (with $\hbar=1$):
$$i\dfrac{d}{dt}\psi(t)=H(t)\psi(t)\ ,$$
where $\psi$ is some normalized column vector and $H(t)$ is a Hermitian matrix with time-dependent elements.

Let $\Psi(t)=U(t)\psi(t)$, where $U(t)$ is unitary. It can be shown that the time-dependent Schrödinger equation in terms of $\Psi$ can be written as:
$$i\dfrac{d}{dt}\Psi(t)=\left[UHU^{-1}-iU\dot{\left(U^{-1}\right)}\right]\Psi(t)\ ,$$
where the overdot indicates element-wise time derivative. Is it possible to find a $U$ such that this new Hamiltonian $UHU^{-1}-iU\dot{\left(U^{-1}\right)}$ is real symmetric?

A simple solution can be found when $H$ is 2 x 2, by assuming that $U$ is diagonal. But, this method fails for higher dimensional cases. Can it be done under some special conditions? Can it be done if $U$ is invertible, but not necessarily unitary?

---

I have confirmed that it is possible for the 3x3 case by doing a brute-force computation using the parametric form for a 3x3 special unitary matrix.

Comment: Choose $U$ wih each column is the energy eigen-states of $H$. Essentially, diagonalize the Hamiltonian.

Comment: @K_inverse that only works if $U$ does not depend on time, but here the additional $-iU\dot{\left(U^{-1}\right)}$ term messes that up.

Comment: I would expect it to work, since unitary $U$ has $n^2$ degrees of freedom, and making $UHU^\dagger + i \dot U U^\dagger$ real is only $n^2 / 2 - n / 2$ conditions. But I don't have a proof.

Comment: Or rather, $n^2 - 1$ because a global phase doesn't do anything. Note that diagonal unitary $U$ has only $n-1$ d.o.f., so it should not work in any $n>2$.

Comment: @Noiralef I thought that d.o.f. argument only works if the unknown variables are in a linear system. If the elements of $U$ are not bijective functions, then that argument can easily fail.

Comment: Yes, that is correct! I just wanted to say: I can't prove that it is possible, but it feels like it could be.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done in general in a kind of trivial way. Let $U$ be $V^\dagger$, where $V$ is the time-evolution operator. The Schrodinger equation gives that $i \frac{dV}{dt} = H V$, so
$$U H U^\dagger - i U \frac{dU^\dagger}{dt} = V^\dagger H V - i V^\dagger \frac{dV}{dt} = V^\dagger H V - V^\dagger H V = 0,$$
and the zero matrix is certainly real symmetric. This works regardless of whether the Hamiltonian is time-dependent.